# Am not able to check if month == equal datetime

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to show results of each month.
Im having this `for` loop:

```
foreach ($overview as $day) {
    $year = date("Y") - 1;
    if ($day->user == $info->id) {
        $startDate = new DateTime($day->Calendar_startdate);
        $endDate = new DateTime($day->Calendar_enddate);
        $s = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');
        $e = $endDate->format('Y-m-d');
        if ($s > $year) {
            $workdays = number_of_working_days($s, $e);
            $daysleft = $daysleft + $workdays;
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

This `for` loop is also in an `if` statement which echos the months.

Now I need to let it work for the months January, February etc...
I am able to not show results if in the previous year which works well.

Comment: This is not a **`for`** loop...

Comment: whoops i know its an foreach sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by checking each month if it contained for example -01-

`DB::table('Calendar')->where('Calendar_startdate', 'like','%' . $monthnumber . '%')->where('user', $info->id)->where('Calendar_type',2)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare `$s` with `$year` just change `$year` to :

```
$time = new DateTime('now');
/*** you can use `now` for today
/* or you can change to a fixed date exmp: 2016-01-01
*/
$year = $time->modify('-1 year')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Than you can compare `$s > $year`

Comment: well i can already compare the year because it filters out the results of the previous year.
i need to check if the date is in the month january february march april etc.
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4ysr9d9ysya1pu/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-11%20at%2009.11.07.png?dl=0 attached is an screen shot for what i mean its a system which checks each month how many days off each employee has.